# Force install graphics driver that is compatible only with previous version of Windows

Tags: graphics-card, display-driver, ati-mobility-radeon

I have a desktop running Windows 8. I've installed it recently. But the problem is, I cannot install the graphics driver. The graphics card is **ATI Radeon Xpress 200 series**. When I try, *"Update driver software"*, it says driver isn't compatible with this version of Windows. It worked fine with Windows 7. I also tried disabling driver signature enforcement mode. But it didn't work either.

So, is it possible to force the installation of driver??? Or are there any alternatives without downgrading Windows????

Comment: That's a 13-year old card, which hasn't been supported since about 2006. Last drivers were for WinXP. You could replace it with something 10 times faster for about 20 bucks/euros/shekels & save on your electricity bill too.

Comment: But it did work on Windows 7. I want to just use it as a dummy PC. So it would be nice if I can see some smooth transition and do projecting stuff. By the way, the hardware is old too.

Comment: You could try forcing another ATI driver. Alternatively, if you look at the `.inf` file for the driver, you will see the supported operating systems. If you're lucky it may still work on W8, but the `.inf` file hasn't been updated. You can create an updated copy of this file yourself, but there will be no-one to blame but yourself if it all goes wrong and the system becomes unbootable. Take a system snapshot beforehand (or preferably a partition copy), so you can recover your current system again.

Comment: But how to do that?? Here is the link for `inf` file: [C2_47989.inf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2cIef7-mz6nNVoyMFMxRUFEeEE) [Cx_47989.inf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2cIef7-mz6nZWo1V2FIQ2J5ZWc)

Comment: Well. I tried changing `NTx86` to `NTx86.6.3` (My OS is Windows 8.1). But it didn't work. Or should I change something else???